# The type or namespace name 'ClipboardEventArgs' could not be found

Tags: c#

Hi have start a new application and i need to implement copy to clipboard to detect wen the user have copy the text from the textbox i have try to use this example but i get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'ClipboardEventArgs' could not be found
```

this is a class i use to do the trick but its seems i have fail some thing.

my Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace OpenPop.TestApplication
{
    public partial class ClipboardTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private const int WM_CUT = 0x0300;
        private const int WM_COPY = 0x0301;
        private const int WM_PASTE = 0x0302;

        public delegate void ClipboardEventHandler(object sender, ClipboardEventArgs e);

        [Category("Clipboard")]
        public event ClipboardEventHandler CutText;
        [Category("Clipboard")]
        public event ClipboardEventHandler CopiedText;
        [Category("Clipboard")]
        public event ClipboardEventHandler PastedText;

        public ClipboardTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            if (m.Msg == WM_CUT)
            {
                if (CutText != null)
                    CutText(this, new ClipboardEventArgs(this.SelectedText));
            }
            else if (m.Msg == WM_COPY)
            {
                if (CopiedText != null)
                    CopiedText(this, new ClipboardEventArgs(this.SelectedText));
            }
            else if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
            {
                if (PastedText != null)
                    PastedText(this, new ClipboardEventArgs(Clipboard.GetText()));
            }

            base.WndProc(ref m);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got that code from https://github.com/ispysoftware/iSpy/blob/master/Controls/ClipboardTextBox.cs but you failed to copy it all.  If you're going to use someone elses code, you should cite the original author, *especially* when the original software requires it in its license.  In this case, iSpy is LGPL.

Comment: Amy does seem to have the size of it. In general if you are having problems with code you got from elsewhere then you should say where you got the code from. Often, as seems to be the case here, there is context that you have removed by transcribing edited highlights. In general though had Amy not found that code I would be asking what you think `ClipboardEventArgs` is supposed to be referring to - if this is code you wrote then you must have some idea of what it should be...

Comment: No in fact i have copy from stackoverflow

Comment: But its seems the same to me to. I dint know

Comment: Finally i have the page were i got the original code its from http://www.vcskicks.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well In fact i solved the problem in a different way, so i have delete this class and i have replace all this class by

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText(messageTextBox.SelectedText);
        MessageBox.Show("You Have Copy The Link The Message Will Bee Delete Now...");
        deletemenssage();
    }
```